# Is there a way to extract POI's from Garmin map format (mdx img tdb mdr)?

Tags: php, javascript, gps, maps, garmin

I've got the following files that are provided in Garmin format:

1. file.img
2. file.MDX
3. file.TDB
4. file_mdr.img

I need to find a way to extract Points of Interests from these files. Do you know any library/technique to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) community knows how those maps work, because they can make their own maps for them. Maybe there is a tool on their website that can extract the POIs from the files?